# Dart flutter inharitance

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ParentClass with property _prop that you can get with a getter.

I have a ChildClass that needs this prop. The value of child's property must always be set to the value of parent prop. Child can't change it.

What is the right syntex for this?

Comment: Could you please share the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to do like this:

```dart
class ParentClass {
  ParentClass();
  
  get prop => _prop;
  
  dynamic _prop;
  
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
  
  @override
  dynamic get prop => super._prop; // or super.prop in other class

  some() {
    print(prop); // it is ok
    prop = 5; // mistake
  }
}
```

Comment: That is close, but I would like to set it as a property of child class. How can I do that? Thank you!!

Comment: You can use the annotation `@override` for prop in ChildClass. Check again answer

Comment: Thank you again! Just one more question - is there any way to set it in the constructor?

Comment: in ChildClass or ParentClass?

Comment: In child (so that you set it to super.prop or something like that).

Comment: `ChildClass(dynamic prop) : super(prop);` and add `ParentClass(this._prop);`

Comment: I can't do that in parent, since parent class is predefined. Is there any way to do something like class ChildClass {final property; ChildClass({this.property = super.prop}).

Comment: I really appreciate all the help, thanks a ton. I'm stuck with this problem and can't find the right solution.

Comment: Attach a sample code so I understand the context. Or, try this `ChildClass() {
    prop = super._prop;
  }

  @override
  late final prop;`

Comment: It's the same as yours in the main answer, only difference is that I can't modify the parent + the child needs this prop as a property, not via method. I need to modify the child all the time (but need this property to remain the same throughout changes). So for example, when I do copyWith on the child, I need to keep this prop the same.

Comment: I get 'the default value of an optional parameter must be constant'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249457/discussion-between-ruble-and-may).